How Can I Navigate To Another Page
//ViewEntry.kt
@Composable
fun createCard(diaryEntries: List<DiaryEntry>, navController: NavController) {
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        items(diaryEntries) { entry ->
            OutlinedCard(
                colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(
                    containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surface,
                ),
                border = BorderStroke(1.dp, Color.Black),
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(100.dp)
                    .padding(horizontal = 16.dp, vertical = 8.dp)
                    .clickable {
                        navController.navigate("ViewDiaryEntry/${entry.id}")
                    }
            ) {
                Row(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
                ) {
                    Text(
                        text = formatDate(entry.date),
                        fontSize = 25.sp,
                        fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


//ViewDiaryDetail.kt
@Composable
fun ViewDiaryEntry(entry: DiaryEntry, navController: NavController){
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("DiaryEntries", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

    Column {
        AppBarForDiaryView(
            title = "Diary Entry",
            onBackPressed = {
                navController.popBackStack()
            }
        )
        ViewTheDetails(entry = entry)
    }
}

Clickable is not working, I mean when I click the card it does not give me the diary details page, the screen goes black and the app stops runnig.
How can I rectify this ?

Looks like the app is crashing. Please update your question with the stack trace and tell us the which line of your code that corresponds to. Please also see if this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Try defining the route with arguments in the navigation graph you're calling on the clickable action.
Something like this:
composable(
    route = Route.PROFILE_SCREEN + "/{userId}",
    arguments = listOf(
        navArgument("userId") {
            type = NavType.StringType
        }),
) {
    val userId = it.arguments?.getString("userId") ?: ""

    ProfileScreen(
        vm = profileViewModel,
        id = userId,
    )
}


It seems like your app is crashing because you're likely passing an argument in the navigation but not receiving it correctly in the nav graph.
First, avoid passing the navController directly to the composable. Instead, consider using a callback to the nav graph as shown below:
@Composable
fun ViewDiaryEntry(entry: DiaryEntry, onBackPressed: () -> Unit){
val context = LocalContext.current
val sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("DiaryEntries", 
Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

Column {
    AppBarForDiaryView(
        title = "Diary Entry",
        onBackPressed = {
            onBackPressed.invoke()
        }
    )
    ViewTheDetails(entry = entry)
}
}

Now, in your NavGraph, implement the following steps:
composable(
    route = "ViewDiaryEntry" + "/{entryId}",
    arguments = listOf(
        navArgument("entryId") {
            type = NavType.StringType
        }),
) {
    val entryId = it.arguments?.getString("entryId") ?: ""

    ViewDiaryEntry(
        entery = DiaryEntery(), // if you want to pass an object then try 
//to convert it json string and pass it as string and then convert to 
//object
        onBackPressed = {navController.popBackStack()},
    )
}

You can use either the Gson or Moshi library to convert an object to a JSON string and then parse it back into an object.
